# How to extend as.list in a canonical way to S4 objects

Tags: r, r-s4

I am having some trouble converting my S4 object back into a list. Take for example, the following nested S4 classes:

```
setClass("nssItem", 
         representation(value = "numeric", text = "character", prefix = "character", type = "character"),
         prototype(value = as.numeric(NA), text = as.character(NA), prefix = as.character(NA), type = as.character(NA))

         ) 

setClass("geckoNss", representation(absolute = "character", item = "nssItem"))
```

An object of `geckoNss` class contains objects of `nssItem` class. Conceptually this seems like a list-like structure which allows for nesting.

Yet,

```
> temp <- new("nssItem")
> as.list(temp)
Error in as.list.default(temp) : 
  no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector
```

I understand this error, that is, I have not actually defined what `as.list` means or how it applies with respect to the `nssItem` class. Nonetheless, this seems like a very natural operation. How would I extend the definition of `as.list` to all new classes I define?

Answer (score 4):

This is a second, more general solution. It uses a superclass from which you derive all user-defined classes. Descriptions are in the `#` comments.

```
#this is an "empty" superclass that characterises all user-defined classes
setClass("user_defined_class")

#we create an as.list method for this new superclass (this time an S4 method)
setMethod("as.list",signature(x="user_defined_class"),function(x) {
  mapply(function(y) {
    #apply as.list if the slot is again an user-defined object
    #therefore, as.list gets applied recursively
    if (inherits(slot(x,y),"user_defined_class")) {
      as.list(slot(x,y))
    } else {
      #otherwise just return the slot
      slot(x,y)
    }
  },
slotNames(class(x)),
SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
})

setClass("nssItem", 
     representation(value = "numeric",
                    text = "character",
                    prefix = "character",
                    type = "character"),
     prototype(value = as.numeric(NA),
               text = as.character(NA),
               prefix = as.character(NA),
               type = as.character(NA)),
     #note the contains argument that flags the nssItem class as user-defined
     contains="user_defined_class")

setClass("geckoNss",
         representation(absolute = "character", item = "nssItem"),
         #the same for the geckoNss class
         contains="user_defined_class")
```

Now create one object for each class

```
temp <- new("nssItem")
tempGecko<-new("geckoNss")
```

Coerce `temp` to list

```
as.list(temp)
#$value
#[1] NA
#
#$text
#[1] NA
#
#$prefix
#[1] NA
#
#$type
#[1] NA
```

And the `tempGecko` object

```
as.list(tempGecko)
#$absolute
#character(0)
#
#$item
#$item$value
#[1] NA
#
#$item$text
#[1] NA
#
#$item$prefix
#[1] NA
#
#$item$type
#[1] NA
```

Comment: It's a very beautiful solution! However, it relies on the `item` representation to be of class `nssItem`. This would be a separate question but I require the `item` representation to be a list of objects of `nssItem`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether I have understood your argument about "nesting" correctly, but here some code on how to extend `as.list` to your `S4` classes. As noted by Alex in the comments, these are actually `S3` methods that are used on the `S4` objects. This works as well. You can find a nice summary about this topic here [Combining S4 and S3 methods in a single function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12100856/combining-s4-and-s3-methods-in-a-single-function)

```
as.list.nssItem=function(from) mapply(function(x) slot(from,x),
                                      slotNames("nssItem"),
                                      SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

Now let's try `as.list` on the `nssItem` object `temp` (as defined in your post)

```
as.list(temp)
#$value
#[1] NA
#
#$text
#[1] NA
#
#$prefix
#[1] NA
#
#$type
#[1] NA
```

Edit: I think I now understand what you mean by nesting. After executing the code above, define a new `geckoNss` object

```
tempGecko<-new("geckoNss")
```

Extend `as.list` to class `geckoNss`

```
as.list.geckoNss=function(from) mapply(function(x) {
  if (x=="item") as.list(slot(from,x)) else slot(from,x)
  },
  slotNames("geckoNss"),
  SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

Now apply `as.list` to your `geckoNss` object `tempGecko`

```
as.list(tempGecko)

#$absolute
#character(0)
#
#$item
#$item$value
#[1] NA
#
#$item$text
#[1] NA
#
#$item$prefix
#[1] NA
#
#$item$type
#[1] NA
```

---

As per Alex comment below, here a more general way of extending `as.list`.

```
#save old function definition (just in case...)
as.list.default.save=as.list.default
```

Define new default method

```
as.list.default=function(x) {
  if (class(x)=='list') {
    x
  } else if (class(x)%in%c('nssItem','geckoNss')) {
    mapply(function(slot_name) as.list(slot(x,slot_name)),
           slotNames(class(x)),
           SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
  } else {
    .Internal(as.vector(x, "list"))
  }
}
```

You still have to enter a vector of all your user-defined classes `c('nssItem','geckoNss')`. I haven't been able to find a function that returns these classes.
The result is not as nicely formated as above...

```
as.list(temp)

#$value
#$value[[1]]
#[1] NA
#
#
#$text
#$text[[1]]
#[1] NA
#
#
#$prefix
#$prefix[[1]]
#[1] NA
#
#
#$type
#$type[[1]]
#[1] NA
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It is very helpful to actually let me extend `as.list` to these two objects and also convert the nested s4 objects into nested lists. I think the same unpackaging concept could extend to other new classes, but I don't want to have to write as `as.list` method for all of them. That is what I meant by "canonical" in the question title.

Comment: I have another question, can you use the `as.list.<classname>` method to define new methods on s4 classes? I thought this was a S3 way of defining a method

Comment: @Alex When R does not find an S4 method it uses the S3 method (if available). You can also define an S4 method.

Comment: Excellent, the newest edit is getting the function to where I would like it. Would we be able to use `rapply` to preserve the nested structure? I am interested in how to obtain all available classes as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30363558/how-do-i-see-existing-classes

Comment: @Alex I think I have found a better solution now. I will post it in a separate answer.